# Sending Base64 data to Controller of Type GET

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-web-api, base64

I am working on MVC WebAPI project. I created controller that needs to accept the Base64 data.

```
[HttpGet]
 public string getData(string fileData)
    { .. Further Operations .. }
```

Currently, I am using Postman/Telerik Fiddler to check my APIs.

Few things,

1. Is it possible to send Base64 data to controller of type GET(without using FormData class)?

   - because in POST and PUT we can use FormData class and send data to controller
2. if it is can anyone please tell me how can I check my scenario in Postman/Fiddler?

If you can suggest me any another tool that will also be great

Thank You

Comment: it's possible to send data with GET request but generally base64 string is larger so it will exceed urlsize limit and will not send complete data

it's advisible to use POST or PUT

Comment: The Base64 data I am sending has nothing to do with Database so I just tried it with GET (if possible)

Comment: it's not about database and GET, POST request it's what operation you are trying to do. POST or PUT means you are sending some data to your backend or rest service.

Comment: Thats why I am saying.. There is no Backend in my project I am working on some other stuff. No DB Connection. No EF. You can treat that method as normal method of Controller and that I want to call.

Comment: The way you send data in a get request is through query string. Sending base64 encoded is not a good idea as it will contain special characters. You can use post without a backend and do whatever with the data you get from body. Look for FromQuery, FromBody bindings in ASP.

Comment: @Pro-n-apps: read up on how the HTTP protocol works.  That should clear up the confusion and put you and sramalingam24 on equal footing.

Comment: I tried this 
   public async Task<List<string>> getData([FromBody]string fileData)
        {
            string base64Image = fileData;
            var t = base64Image.Substring(22);
   ........
         }

But value of fileData is null

Comment: Anyways I got answer.. Finally, I end up with POST only. I was just looking for way to call controller type GET. Still if anyone has an answer for GET they can post..